# How to open many excel file and open them in DataGridView

Tags: c#

I'm writing a program to filter many Excel files and show the results in DataGridView. I started with `OpenFileDialog` (I can choose one file path) to show that my filter works, but now I want to choose many files and open them in `DataGridView` and then filter them.

Is there a Component in WFA (Visual Studio) that does this? I mean like OpenFileDialog but it opens/selects many files?
I tried with this code but it show the last selected file,
Thank you!

enter code here

```
private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {

            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

            openFileDialog1.Filter = "XML Files, Text Files, Excel Files| *.xlsx; *.xls; *.xml; *.txt; "; ;
            openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {

                foreach (String file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
                {
                    tb_path.Text = file;

                    // excelFilePath_com = tb_path.Text;

                    }


            }
            string constr = string.Format("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source =" + tb_path.Text + ";Extended Properties = \"Excel 12.0; HDR=Yes;\"; ");

                    OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(constr);
                    con.Open();
                    drop_down_sheet.DataSource = con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
                    drop_down_sheet.DisplayMember = "TABLE_NAME";
                    drop_down_sheet.ValueMember = "TABLE_NAME";


            }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message,
         "Important Note",
         MessageBoxButtons.OK,
         MessageBoxIcon.Error,
         MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
        }

    }
```

Comment: [OpenFileDialog.Multiselect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.openfiledialog.multiselect?view=netframework-4.8#Microsoft_Win32_OpenFileDialog_Multiselect)

Comment: Hi @Osama Please post your working code so that we can advise you better. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OpenFileDialog control has the property `Multiselect` that will allow you to select multiple files in the same dialog.

```
openFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel files|*.xlsx|All files|*.*";
openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
```

Then later you can use the property `Filenames` (instead of `Filename`) to retrieve your files:

```
foreach (string filePath in openFileDialog1.FileNames)   
{
    // ...
}
```

[Check MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.multiselect?view=netframework-4.8) for more info.

Comment: Hi! I can choose multiselect now but it just the first one oppened. have to change any thing in my code or not?

Comment: Hi, I have provided the code but it will open the last path only e.g  I oppen three files 10,11,12 the datagridview show just 12, what should I do here, If you want I can add my code here

Comment: @Osama Seems like you have a problem with the code you have for adding the paths to the datagrid. Edit your question or add a new one, and include your code

Comment: @SysDragon Thank you for answer I edit my qution now. I hope it is work

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use a `foreach` loop to loop through all the files you want to to open.

```
openFileDialog1.Filter = "Excel files (*.xlsx)|All files (*.*)|*.*";
openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;

foreach (String file in openFileDialog1.FileNames)
{
    //do what you need with the files. 
    //eg: file.Open();
}
```